# how to open the tauri application located on the server

Tags: linux, windows, web, server, tauri

I created a new tauri app on a shared server (timeweb) and tried to run the project, the first run got a bunch of errors, which I successfully fixed by installing packages for linux on the server side. after that, the errors disappeared, but another problem appeared at the next start, these messages

Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(first-project:508358): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:49:35.766: cannot open display: 0:0

pop up. I tried to find a solution on the Internet, but I didn’t find it, please help me in advance thanks :*

Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(first-project:508358): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:49:35.766: cannot open display: 0:0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general error that appears because you are trying to launch a tauri application, which is a graphical application, while through `ssh` (or some other console not connected to the desktop environment).

You can launch it by giving it a fake display:

```bash
DISPLAY=:0 nohup tauri-application 2>/dev/null 1>&2 &
```

`DISPLAY=:0` sets the `DISPLAY` variable to the `:0` value, which is usually the local desktop
`nohup` makes the application ignore `SIGHUP` signals, so your application outlives your console connection.
`2>/dev/null` redirects all errors to `/dev/null/`, so that you don't see them on the console. This is made so you can continue to use your console after starting.
`1>&2` redirects stdout to stderr
 `&` makes the application start in the background.

You can also issue a `disown` command afterwards, assuming a normal linux distro, so that you can more accurately simulate starting the application as you would graphically, so your console doesn't have any relation to the application anymore.

Nothing from above is specific to starting tauri applications, you can start many graphical applications like that.

Of course, more practical would be to forward your X server through ssh, so that you can see your application on your system, even though it is running remotely. You can do that with `ssh -X` and just start the app as normal, without all the above.